# uidatepicker always rolls to current time

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

[image]
[image]

Datepicker always scrolls to current time once the button is pressed, and also datepicker time does not get displayed.

I am setting up a datepicker. I am trying to connect datepicker and button to label to show correct time.
I have connected a "PickUp ASAP" Button to " @IBAction func buttonPressed" as shown in code ahead, which works fine i.e shows current date and time in the "Label" when pressed (here it is 2019 11 06 04:20: PM) (see images above and code below). So, it is all fine here.

Now, I have also tried to connect the "@IBAction func datePickerChanged" to show current date and time of the  in the "Label"when scrolled(see images above and code below).

1. My main problem is that once I  press the "PickUP ASAP" Button, no matter what I do, the datepicker always scrolls back to current date and time. Even if I scroll the datepicker to a different date, it always scrolls back to current date and time.
2. Another problem is that "Label" does not show any date and time of the datepicker, if I  scroll the datepicker without clicking the "Pickup ASAP" button. I  want the "Label" to show the date and time of the datepicker when scrolled.

Also,  the format of display in the "Label" when I press either "Pickup ASAP" button or scroll the datepicker should be the same.

I am attaching necessary screenshots of simulator as well as storyboard respectively above.

```
     import UIKit

     @IBDesignable class testdateViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!

     @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIDatePicker!

     @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

      picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .valueChanged)
      let currentDateTime = Date()

      let formatter = DateFormatter()

      formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd hh:mm:  a"

      Label.text = " \( (formatter.string(from: currentDateTime)))"

      picker.date =  currentDateTime
    }

      override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

     let datepicker = UIDatePicker()

     datepicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testdateViewController.datePickerChanged), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
     }

     @IBAction func datePickerChanged(_ sender: Any) {

     let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
     let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
     Label.text = strDate
     }

     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
     super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
       }
     }
```

Comment: Why the ViewController is  `@IBDesignable class` ?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed -- ok, it can be removed. It does not matter, forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code Update:**

Remove this code from `ViewDidLoad()`

```
let datepicker = UIDatePicker()
datepicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testdateViewController.datePickerChanged), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
```

and use this in `ViewDidLoad()`

```
 picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testdateViewController.datePickerChanged), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
```

Move some code from `buttonPressed` method to `datePickerChanged`.

**datePickerChanged**  will look like

```
@IBAction func datePickerChanged(_ sender: Any) {
     updateData(date: picker.date) 
 }
```

If you want to show current date in the label then you can manager another method to set the value to the label like this

```
func updateData(date: Date) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd hh:mm:  a"
    let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: picker.date)
    Label.text = strDate
}
```

And in ViewDidLoad() method add this

```
 updateData(date: Date()) // This will show the current date value
```

In final `ViewDidLoad()` will look like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad() 
   picker.date =  Date() // You can set any date initially that you want. This will be a date object 
   picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testdateViewController.datePickerChanged), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
   updateData(date: Date())
 }
```

And also remove all the code from `buttonPressed`. Because during the initial load it will show the current time on the label.

The full code will look like

```
import UIKit

class testdateViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        picker.date =  Date() // You can set any date initially that you want. This will be a date object
        picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testdateViewController.datePickerChanged), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        updateData(date: Date())

    }

    @IBAction func datePickerChanged(_ sender: Any) {
       updateData(date: picker.date)
    }

    func updateData(date: Date) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd hh:mm:  a"
        let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: picker.date)
        Label.text = strDate
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help you.

Comment: You missed stepns in IBAction func buttonPressed - The complete function is -        IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
       
        let currentDateTime = Date()
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd hh:mm:  a"
        
        Label.text = " \( (formatter.string(from: currentDateTime)))"
        
        picker.date =  currentDateTime
    }// please rectify it.

Comment: also " picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .valueChanged)" step should be removed. so, "IBAction func buttonPressed " should look as in my above comment

Comment: What actually you want to do in the button press?

Comment: ASAP - "As Soon As possible"

Answer (score 0):

```
    1. My main problem is that once I press the "PickUP ASAP" Button, no matter what I do, the datepicker always scrolls back to the current date and time. Even if I scroll the datePicker to a different date, it always scrolls back to the current date and time.

    Answer:- Because you set the current date to date picker in "PickUP ASAP" Button action.

    2. Another problem is that "Label" does not show any date and time of the datepicker, if I scroll the datepicker without clicking the "Pickup ASAP" button. I want the "Label" to show the date and time of the datepicker when scrolled.

    Answer:- In `viewDidLoad()` please replace the line with `picker = UIDatePicker()` and remove 
             `let datePicker = UIDatePicker()` from `datePickerChanged` method. Also  Please specify the format for the `DateFormatter()` in `datePickerChanged` method.

 Look at the code below:-

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    picker = UIDatePicker()
    picker.datePickerMode = .date
    picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testdateViewController.datePickerChanged), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
}

func datePickerChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    setDateValue()
}

func setDateValue() {
    let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
    dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
    let str = dateFormat.string(from: picker.date)
    Label.text = str
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    setDateValue()
}
```

Comment: @Nexus  and Faysal I  believe you want viewdidload method to be changed as follows with no other changes in the code -                                                           override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
func datePickerChanged(_ sender: Any) {
picker = UIDatePicker()/*yell err - Instance will be immediately deallocated because property 'picker' is 'weak'*/
let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
let str = dateFormat.string(from: picker.date)
Label.text = str
} } // Still NO AVAIL. I can give github link to the full code if you want

Comment: @askit Did you checked my answer?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed -  sorry no. let me check it. where should I add the code then.